# Transferring files from unix server to shared folder in cloud through network?

Tags: unix, network-protocols

I am presently Transferring files from unix server to a shared folder in cloud manually by copying files from unix server and then loading in to cloud shared  folder.I would like to automate this by running a shell script in unix server.Unable to implement with Ftp,scp and ssh protocols as the destination is a shared folder.

Presently I am logging in to unix server through my windows desktop using putty. Now I am connecting to cloud shared folder through mapping network drive (I have cloud path) then copying in to drive where my system is adding as intermediate one. Now I want to make this movement directly with a worksheduler where the script runs in the unix by which the files must be moved to cloud.

Comment: Hello Sai Vineel, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you [edit] your question to add a bit more detail please? It would easier to help you if you could include examples of how you are currently transferring files "manually" - do you mean with individual [cp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_(Unix))  shell commands, or something else?

Comment: Hi Vince Bowdren, Presently I am logging in to unix server through my windows desktop using putty.Now I am connecting to cloud shared folder through mapping network drive(I have cloud  path ) then copying in to drive where my system is adding as intermediate one.Now I want to make this movement directly with a worksheduler where the script runs in the unix by which the files must be moved to cloud.

Answer (score 0):

rsync path/*.txt server2:/path

The rsync remote-update protocol allows rsync to transfer just the differences between two sets of files across the network link.
Also for copying from the local machine to a remote machine using a remote shell program as the transport (such as rsh or ssh). This is invoked when the destination path contains a single : separator.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hi sschand, I forgot to mention that I have only the memory which is in the  cloud I cant install anything there (Cant install rsync in remote system)